# How do I test a website for memory leaks?

Tags: javascript, java, html, memory-leaks, performance-testing

I want to test a website from a performance point of view.  When there are a lot of user events on this website it eventually grinds to a halt and goes down.  It is written in Java and has some Javascript too.  I have been viewing the developer tools on chrome to see if I can narrow down the areas that are causing memory leaks.

Do people reccomend any tools or youtube clips detailing what tests should be run on a website to help identify memory leaks.

Comment: Does the server grind to a halt, or the browser?

Comment: Memory leaks only occur on the server side of your web application. For that part there are various tools like JMeter.

Comment: Java / JavaScript? Where is the leak? The browser  or the Server. Talking two different things here. Also the way this question is worded, it is going to get closed.

Comment: @hotzst Heard of DOM memory leaks ?

Answer (score 2):

For an Java application running in a java server create a integration tests with tools like **JMeter** and configure your server side to be able to peform heapdumps and profiling.

You could profile the server with tools like **VisualVM** that can be connected locally or with JMX if server is not in the same place.

You can check on real time with VisualVM the CPU, Memory,Threads,... and also when all the tests ends execute a Java dump and load the file with the tool **Memory Analyzer**. This tool has in their options a special report to detect memory leaks.

Also for client side some browser like Firefox have a small set of tools to check javascript performance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your site under high load for high amount of time. The best of free and open source tools you can use for it are:

   - Gatling
   - Grinder
   - Tsung
   - Apache JMeter

   See [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) for features overview, how does load test and results look like, etc.
2. Monitor server-side health like CPU and RAM consumption, Disk and Network IO. If above metrics are reasonably low but performance is poor and application halts/crashes you can use the  following tools to get to the bottom of the issue:

   - [JConsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) and/or [JVisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) (both come with Java SDK)
   - [Heap Analyzer](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=4544bafe-c7a2-455f-9d43-eb866ea60091)
   - Profiler like [YourKit or JProfiler](https://blog.oio.de/2014/03/07/java-profilers-a-short-comparison-between-jprofiler-yourkit-and-javas-visualvm/)
3. For client-side performance testing you can use something like [YSlow](http://yslow.org/)